# how setup dfs insted blob endpoint for BlobContainerClient

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

In general, I need to create an app with java that will perform some operations on azure storage
like upload file, append to file, rename, check if exist and so on. And IMPORTANT It has to communicate with DFS endpoint https://xxxx.dfs.core.windows..

But I encounter some problems:

1. during using BlobContainerClient and uploading a file to azure storage an error appears:

> com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: Status code 400,
> "{"error":{"code":"MissingRequiredHeader","message":"An HTTP header
> that's mandatory for this request is not
> specified.\nRequestId:b225d695-201f-00ed-212e-c7c9e8000000\nTime:2021-10-22T10:23:12.4983407Z"}}"

How can I avoid this situation, what header is required and how to set up it?

2. Afterward I have implemented something similar but using DataLakeFileSystemClient and this time uploading of the file was totally fine. Unfortunately, not all operations can be performed. e.g. exists() method internally uses BlobContainerClient
   and perform call via blob endpoint https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.. what if forbidden in my case.
   IMO It is caused because BlobContainerClientBuilder.endpoint(String endpoint) set up endpoint blobContainerClient
   endpoint to blob, and dfs endpoint for DataLakeFileSystemClient.
   source code:

   public DataLakeFileSystemClientBuilder endpoint(String endpoint) { // Ensure endpoint provided is dfs endpoint endpoint = DataLakeImplUtils.endpointToDesiredEndpoint(endpoint, "dfs", "blob"); blobContainerClientBuilder.endpoint(DataLakeImplUtils.endpointToDesiredEndpoint(endpoint, "blob", "dfs"));

So the question is: is it a bug in BlobContainerClientBuilder.endpoint(String endpoint) ?
or how to fix this problem to use the same endpoint for both clients.
Currently, I have implemented wcomunicatend I'm using both clients: DataLakeFileSystemClient to perform actions
like upload, append etc. and BlobContainerClient to check if file exist. I would like to use only one of the clients.

Could you help me somehow, please?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Blob Storage is developed for storing large amount of unstructured data. And Unstructured data does not adhere to a particular data model or definition, such as text or binary data.

Blob Storage provides three resources, which are Storage Account (SA), Container inside SA and a Blob in the Container. And we use some Java classes to interact with these resources.

**The [BlobContainerClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobcontainerclient) class allows you to manipulate Azure Storage Containers and their Blobs**. This class is mainly used to manipulate or work on the Containers (file system). So if you want **to work on or manipulate Blobs (files) then it's recommended to use the [BlobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobclient)**.

Check the following snippets to create a container and uploading a file.

1. Create a container using a `BlobContainerClient`.

   ```
   blobContainerClient.create();
   ```
2. Upload `BinaryData` to a blob using a `BlobClient` generated from a `BlobContainerClient`.

   ```
   BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("myblockblob"); 
   String dataSample = "samples";
   blobClient.upload(BinaryData.fromString(dataSample));
   ```

And to rename a blob (file), **Copy and Delete** is the only method of renaming a blob. If you want to do so for larger blobs, you need to use the asynchronous copy and check periodically for its completion.

Check this [Manage blobs with Java v12 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell#code-examples) and  [Azure Storage Blob client library for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-java-stable) document for more information.